# "Expected end of line but found unknown token." while running AppleScript in swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, applescript

I am trying to run applescript code in swift to get information from other applications.
Here is a sample code:

```
var applescript = "tell application "Xcode" \n set fileName to name of window 1 \n end tell"
var error: NSDictionary?
let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: applescript)
let output: NSAppleEventDescriptor = scriptObject!.executeAndReturnError(&error)
if (error != nil) {
    print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
}
if output.stringValue == nil{
    let empty = "the result is empty"
    return empty
}
else {
    return (output.stringValue?.description)!
}
```

But it always return me error messages like this:

```
error: Optional({
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Expected end of line but found unknown token.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Expected end of line but found unknown token.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2741";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {25, 1}";
})
```

I think the unknown token it mentioned is "\n". Because when I ran other applescripts without "\n" in codes, there was no error message.

Can somebody help me this out? Thank you so much!

Comment: If your AppleScripts are non-trivial, you may find it easier to [call AS handlers directly via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC). It also lets you write your AppleScript code in an external editor (Script Editor/Script Debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the inner double quotes

```
let applescript = "tell application \"Xcode\" \n set fileName to name of window 1 \n end tell"
```

Or, more convenient and more legible with the multiline syntax

```
let applescript = """
    tell application "Xcode"
        set fileName to name of window 1
    end tell
"""
```

Comment: thank you so much for this solution. I have one more question, is there any method that can transfer the first string in your answer to the second one with multiple lines syntax by replacing "\n"?

Comment: What does *transfer* mean? Both forms can be used and do the same thing.

Comment: sorry, I mean "transform". like programmatically transform the first one-line string to the second multiline syntax.

Comment: I still don’t understand. Both are string **literals**.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I think I made a mistake here. Really appreciate your solution and your time!